# Increment value by 1 on submit till it reaches 5

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Good day everyone, 
Im working on a keystroke biometric web app, and I want to prompt the user to input their password **5 times**. 
Now i have the concept in mind, but I can't seem to figure this problem out.
I want to increment **i** by **1** and return false everytime the user clicks submit till **i** becomes **5**, then the form returns true. 
When I click submit, **i** stays 0 and doesn't increment.
This is my code:

```
//When user submits increment by 1 till 5
function formSubmit(){
  for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    if(i <= 4){
      console.log(i);
      return false;
    }else{
      return true;
    }
    }
}
```

And this is the form. I might have an idea that the function is exiting when it returns false and not staying in the for loop, but I tried multiple solutions and nothing worked.

```
 <form onsubmit="return formSubmit()" class="" action="" method="post">
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: use preventDefault to avoid the refresh and increment the i after every single submit

Comment: `return` ends the function execution. Your loop runs exactly once, until the line `return false;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to loop on submit. You need to instead increment a variable outside the function scope each time the form is submitted and when that variable reaches 5 you return `true`.

e.g.

```js
var count = 0;
function formSubmit() {
  console.log(count);
  return ++count === 5;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return formSubmit()" class="" action="" method="post">
  <input type="submit"></input>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what i wanted!